# Vagrant vbox 45-50% CPU usage

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu-usage, vagrant

I am running a headless Ubuntu server box  on my Windows 7 64 bit PC with Vagrant.

My PC has 8 GB ram and Intel Dual Core 3.16Ghz E8500 processor and PAE.

The problem is that VBox routinely uses btw 35-50% CPU, thus negating the benefits of Vagrant.  If I am running Sublime text, Chrome, and Photoshop, my computer slows to a crawl, and being able to use such apps is the primary reason for using Vagrant instead of just dual booting.

I've tried to find help with Google but all solutions including disabling nested paging, etc.  either didn't work or were more confusing than I was prepared for.

I read about setting a CPU cap, and that may be the answer, but what is the theoretical low that I can set the cpu cap to?  Or is there a better solution that it haven't come across?